# How to group a csv file and make a nested dictionary out of it in C#?

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have a csv file and I want to make a nested dictionary out of it. The file looks like this:

```
FilmMaker,   MovieTitle,      EndDate
FunnyM,      F1,              20191210
FunnyM,      F2,              20191211
FunnyM,      F3,              20191212
FunnyM,      F4,              20191213
FunnyM,      F5,              20191214
SadM,        S1,              20191210
SadM,        S2,              20191211
SadM,        S3,              20191212
SadM,        S4,              20191213
SadM,        S5,              20191214
ScaryM,      C1,              20191210
ScaryM,      C2,              20191211
ScaryM,      C3,              20191212
ScaryM,      C4,              20191213
ScaryM,      C5,              20191214
```

I want to `1)`group them by FilmMaker and `2)`sort them by EndDate, and `3)`select movies that ends after 2019-12-10, and also `4)`select only that ends the second earliest. And then, I want to `5)`make a dictionary that has keys as MovieTitle and also has other two columns as values. The result will look like:

```
new_dictionary = {'F3': {'FilmMaker':'FunnyM', 'EndDate':20191012},
                  'S3': {'FilmMaker':'SadM',   'EndDate':20191012},
                  'C3': {'FilmMaker':'ScaryM', 'EndDate':20191012} }
```

I've looked up on the internet, but I couldn't find how to make a nested dictionary out of a csv file with multiple conditions. This is what I have figured out so far:

```
Dictionary<string, string[]> result = File.ReadLines("movies.csv")
                                            .Skip(1)
                                            .Select(line => line.Split(','))
                                            .GroupBy(arr => arr[0])              
                                            .ToDictionary(gr => gr.Key,
                                                          gr => gr.Select(s => s[1]).ToArray());
```

I think there should be `OrderBy` and `Where`, and the dictionary has to be set as `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> dic_movies = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();` but I don't know how to get it done altogether.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to trim the columns.

```
.Select(line => line.Split(',').Select(s => s.Trim()).ToList())
```

## Following the instructions

> how do you sort them by EndDate and get the nth value only for each group, not the certain date value?

Here is version that follows the procedure outlined in the question.

```
var data = @"FilmMaker,   MovieTitle,      EndDate
    FunnyM,      F1,              20191210
    FunnyM,      F2,              20191211
    FunnyM,      F3,              20191212
    FunnyM,      F4,              20191213
    FunnyM,      F5,              20191214
    SadM,        S1,              20191210
    SadM,        S2,              20191211
    SadM,        S3,              20191212
    SadM,        S4,              20191213
    SadM,        S5,              20191214
    ScaryM,      C1,              20191210
    ScaryM,      C2,              20191211
    ScaryM,      C3,              20191212
    ScaryM,      C4,              20191213
    ScaryM,      C5,              20191214";

var d = data.Split("\r\n")
    .Skip(1)
    .Select(line => line.Split(',').Select(s => s.Trim()).ToList())
    .Select( a => new { FilmMaker = a[0], MovieTitle = a[1], EndDate= DateTime.ParseExact(a[2], "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)}) // No error handling for brevity
    // We have crossed the csv/object boundary

    // 1) group them by FilmMaker 
    .GroupBy( o => o.FilmMaker )       
    // 2) sort them by EndDate
    // 3) select movies that ends after 2019-12-10
    // 4) select only that ends the second earliest
    // NOTE: This is quite fragile - if there is no 2nd earliest movie this will throw
    .Select( g => new { FilmMaker = g.Key, Movie = g.Where( m => m.EndDate > new DateTime(2019,12,10)).OrderBy( m => m.EndDate).Skip(1).First() })
    // 5) make a dictionary that has keys as MovieTitle and also has other two columns as values. 
    .ToDictionary( m => m.Movie.MovieTitle,
                   m => new { FilmMaker = m.FilmMaker, EndDate = m.Movie.EndDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd")});


    Console.WriteLine(System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(d));
```

```
{
"F3":{"FilmMaker":"FunnyM","EndDate":"20191212"},
"S3":{"FilmMaker":"SadM","EndDate":"20191212"},
"C3":{"FilmMaker":"ScaryM","EndDate":"20191212"}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed examples. But how do you sort them by EndDate and get ```the nth value only for each group```, not the certain date value?

Answer (score 1):

You could convert the CSV to an intermediate class and then use it for processing before creating the final dictionary. This would enable you to break down the problem into steps and increase readability. For example,

```
public class Movie
{
    public string FilmMaker{get;set;}
    public string MovieTitle{get;set;}
    public DateTime EndDate{get;set;}
}
```

Assuming Movie Class is defined as above, you could Sort the CSV to dictionary as following.

```
var csvCollection = csv.Split(new []{Environment.NewLine},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                                    .Skip(1)
                                    .Select(line => line.Split(',').Select(c=>c.Trim()).ToList());

var movieCollection = csvCollection.Select(x=> new Movie
                                           { 
                                               FilmMaker = x[0], 
                                               MovieTitle = x[1], 
                                               EndDate = DateTime.ParseExact(x[2],"yyyyMMdd",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                                           });

var result = movieCollection.Where(x=> x.EndDate> new DateTime(2019,12,10))
                                .OrderBy(x=>x.EndDate)
                                .GroupBy(x=>x.FilmMaker)
                                .Select(x=> x.Skip(1).First())
                                .ToDictionary(key=>key.MovieTitle,value=>new []{$"FilmMaker:{value.FilmMaker}",$"EndDate:{value.EndDate.Year}{value.EndDate.Month}{value.EndDate.Day}"});
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for helping me. Thanks to your code and explanation, I've learned how it actually works!

Answer (score 1):

Use a library such as CsvHelper to parse the csv, do not do it by hand.

Once you've read the records in, then it's just a matter of filtering, sorting, grouping and selecting your desired result.

```
using (var reader = new CsvHelper.CsvReader(File.OpenText(inputFile)))
{
    reader.Configuration.TrimOptions = CsvHelper.Configuration.TrimOptions.Trim;
    var query =
        from r in reader.GetRecords(new { FilmMaker = "", MovieTitle = "", EndDate = "" })
        let date = DateTime.ParseExact(r.EndDate, "yyyyMMdd", default)
        where date > new DateTime(2019, 12, 10)
        orderby date
        group r by r.FilmMaker into g
        select g.First();
    var dict = query.ToDictionary(
        r => r.MovieTitle,
        r => new { r.FilmMaker, r.EndDate }
    );
    // do stuff with dict
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I want to avoid using external libraries if possible this time, but this looks quite readable!